# Why independent word in Scale-independent Pixels and Density-independent Pixels

Tags: android, user-interface, scale, pixel

`Scale-independent Pixels` is scaled  by the user's font size and `Density-independent Pixels` depends on physical density of the screen.Then why their names contain `independent` as they depends on scale and density respectively but independent means "not depending on"?

Comment: `independent pixels` should actually be scaled to the appropriate size regardless (or `independent`) of `density` or `scale`. I think that the idea is that you should be able to determine the size you would like independently from the actual system (so no calculations are required on your part)

Comment: @zgc7009 Scale-independent Pixels is independent of scale of the screen and Density-independent Pixels is independent of density of screen?

Comment: The pixel size themselves are dependent on the system settings, BUT the settings for the pixels don't need to be handled/calculated by you. You can set dimensions using things like dp without having to worry about the settings yourself. In other words, they allow you to set things up in regards to dimensions independent of the devices themselves (as far as dp/sp are concerned). Without this, Android dev would be very difficult with all of the different screen sizes/resolutions.